# query column with $partition

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table that contains details about some other partitioned tables as below:

```
Row    user_email      table_id           job_type
1     jack@test.com   product$20230310   Query
2     john@test.com   item$20230309      Query
3     jim@test.com    product$20230211   Query
4     jack@test.com   product$20220105   Query
5     Alex@test.com   item$20230310      Query
```

I would like to group by user_email and table_id but as partitions are different it will generate one row for each table/partition.

My query:

```
SELECT
  user_email,
  table_id,
  COUNT(*) AS total
FROM
  TABLE
GROUP BY
  user_email,
  table_id
```

Current results:

```
Row    user_email      table_id           total
1     jack@test.com   product$20230310   1
2     john@test.com   item$20230309      1
3     jim@test.com    product$20230211   1
4     jack@test.com   product$20220105   1
5     Alex@test.com   item$20230310      1
```

Desired output:

```
Row    user_email      table_id           total
1     jack@test.com   product            2
2     john@test.com   item               1
3     jim@test.com    product            1
5     Alex@test.com   item               1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you onoly want the first part of the string, you can use [SPLT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions?hl=de#split)

but better would be not to save delimitated columns, why you need the values,. as every split take time and resource that you could spent elsewhere better

```
SELECT
  user_email,
  SPLIT(table_id, '$')[OFFSET(0)]
,
  COUNT(*) AS total
FROM
  TABLE
GROUP BY
  user_email,
  SPLIT(table_id, '$')[OFFSET(0)]
```